# Unity editor script: visible / hidden gizmos

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I want to hide or show a gizmo in programmatically.

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can it be done with built it API from Unity? **No**.

Although, this **can** be done with the help of **reflection** since Unity did not expose the API for that functionality. I did not write this code. It's from [here](http://www.quickfingers.net/quick-bites-05-toggle-all-scene-view-gizmos/).

You can call the `ToggleGizmos(true)` or `ToggleGizmos(false)` function anytime or you can use it as a plugin like below. Any new **Menu** called **Quick Fingers** should be added to Unity.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;

public class SceneViewGizmos {
    private static bool _globalGizmosOn;


    [MenuItem("Quick Fingers/Scene View/Toggle Gizmos &%g")] private static void ToggleAllSceneGizmos() {
        _globalGizmosOn = !_globalGizmosOn;
        ToggleGizmos(_globalGizmosOn);
    }

    [MenuItem("Quick Fingers/Scene View/Disable All Gizmos")] private static void DisableAllSceneGizmos() {
        _globalGizmosOn = false;
        ToggleGizmos(_globalGizmosOn);
    }

    [MenuItem("Quick Fingers/Scene View/Enable All Gizmos")] private static void EnableAllSceneGizmos() {
        _globalGizmosOn = true;
        ToggleGizmos(_globalGizmosOn);
    }

    private static void ToggleGizmos(bool gizmosOn) {
        int val = gizmosOn ? 1 : 0;
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Editor));
        Type type = asm.GetType("UnityEditor.AnnotationUtility");
        if (type != null) {
            MethodInfo getAnnotations = type.GetMethod("GetAnnotations", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            MethodInfo setGizmoEnabled = type.GetMethod("SetGizmoEnabled", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            MethodInfo setIconEnabled = type.GetMethod("SetIconEnabled", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var annotations = getAnnotations.Invoke(null, null);
            foreach (object annotation in (IEnumerable)annotations) {
                Type annotationType = annotation.GetType();
                FieldInfo classIdField = annotationType.GetField("classID", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                FieldInfo scriptClassField = annotationType.GetField("scriptClass", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (classIdField != null && scriptClassField != null) {
                    int classId = (int)classIdField.GetValue(annotation);
                    string scriptClass = (string)scriptClassField.GetValue(annotation);
                    setGizmoEnabled.Invoke(null, new object[] { classId, scriptClass, val });
                    setIconEnabled.Invoke(null, new object[] { classId, scriptClass, val });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286341/how-to-make-handles-in-a-line-editor-rotate-by-rotating-game-object?

Comment: On Unity 2019.4, SetGizmoEnabled requires a fourth parameter (bool addToMostRecentChanged)

Answer (score 0):

You also just call:

```
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.SetShowGizmos(bool show)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? This method has no effect when I invoke it. It is also in a class that Unity doesn't expect you to use...