# How to switch on/off statistics panel in editor while playing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I want to switch this panel on/off by C# script while playing.
Is this possible? Haven't found any Editor API functions for this.

[image: Stats panel in Unity3D]

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with reflection. Modified [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37271944/3785314) answer I made long ago. Below is a working set/get stats function. Tested with *Unity 5.4.0f1*. I put the Unity version so that people won't complain when it stops working. Unity's update can break this anytime if they rename **any** of the variables.

- `GameView` = A class that is used to represent Unity GameView tab in
  the Editor.
- `GetMainGameView` = static function that returns current `GameView`
  instance.
- `m_Stats` = a boolean variable that is used to determine if stats
  should be displayed or not.

Code:

```
//Show/Hide stats
void showStats(bool enableStats)
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Editor));
    Type type = asm.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView");
    if (type != null)
    {
        MethodInfo gameViewFunction = type.GetMethod("GetMainGameView", BindingFlags.Static |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        object gameViewInstance = gameViewFunction.Invoke(null, null);


        FieldInfo getFieldInfo = type.GetField("m_Stats", BindingFlags.Instance |
                                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

        getFieldInfo.SetValue(gameViewInstance, enableStats);
    }
}

//Returns true if stats is enabled
bool statsIsEnabled()
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Editor));
    Type type = asm.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView");
    if (type != null)
    {
        MethodInfo gameViewFunction = type.GetMethod("GetMainGameView", BindingFlags.Static |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        object gameViewInstance = gameViewFunction.Invoke(null, null);


        FieldInfo getFieldInfo = type.GetField("m_Stats", BindingFlags.Instance |
                                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

        return (bool)getFieldInfo.GetValue(gameViewInstance);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
//Show stats
showStats(true);

//Hide stats
showStats(false);

//Read stats
bool stats = statsIsEnabled();
```

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible, unless you are a persistent hacker. GameView is an internal class, not accessible for editor scripting. But hey, there always is an option for good ol' reflection. This question will set you on the right track:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/179775/game-window-size-from-editor-window-in-editor-mode.html

Comment: This looks like a good option!
But how they've found out the exact name of method which does what it does?
How can I find the name of the method I need (and if it exists) ? Is there a list of methods or something?

Comment: Oh i can't answer that one. I've never tried digging into gameView