# Clear Editor Console logs from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my script and I tried to make "" in case it's not one of the cases:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform")
         Debug.Log("Touching Platform");
    else Debug.Log("");
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "OnTop Detector")
    {
        Debug.Log("On Top of Platform");
        
        GameObject findGo  = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
        GameObject findGo1 = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
        
        findGo.transform.parent = findGo1.transform;
    }
    else Debug.Log("");
}
```

But this "" not working. It's not deleting the text from the console while the game is running. And also when i stop the game and running it again it keep showing the last text of the Debug.Log.

I want to clear it if none of the If's happen in my script.

I saw this answer:

[Answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/707636/clear-console-window.html)

But i'm not sure if this is what I need and how to use it. Make a new script ?

And also what about errors. If I clear the Log in the console it will delete also erorrs if there will be some ?

In this screenshot it's in state after I touched the platform and then moved away from it but the text still exist in the console log:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you use this: Debug.ClearDeveloperConsole ();? and might need using UnityEditor;

Comment: Click the Window tab, then Console. This will show you the true console. That console at the bottom of the screen is just the most recent Debug.Log message. It doesn't mean you're touching it right now, it just means that the last debug.log message that was printed occured while you were touching it

Comment: @moshe, did you try the solution I provided?

Comment: @Programmer I'm trying now. Will let you know in few minutes.

Comment: @Programmer I find it working good. Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `Debug.ClearDeveloperConsole()` function is used when you clear logs from an application that was built while *Debug Build* is enabled in your project. There is *no* official API for clearing the Editor log.

Most Editor functionality can be replicated with [`Reflection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx) just like [*hiding Gizmos*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37271944/3785314) and toggling the [*Stats Panel*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234614/3785314). I was going to write one but found [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/956891/view.html) one.

This should clear every log on the Console tab.

```
using System.Reflection;

public void ClearLog()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UnityEditor.ActiveEditorTracker));
    var type = assembly.GetType("UnityEditorInternal.LogEntries");
    var method = type.GetMethod("Clear");
    method.Invoke(new object(), null);
}
```

Now, you can call `ClearLog();` in your else statements.

**EDIT**:

This has changed recently in about ~Unity 2017. Since it is done with reflection, I consider it to change again anytime if any class, variable or function used in this code is renamed by Unity. Below is the new way to do this:

```
public void ClearLog()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UnityEditor.Editor));
    var type = assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.LogEntries");
    var method = type.GetMethod("Clear");
    method.Invoke(new object(), null);
}
```

Comment: This works as of Unity 2023.1.0B12

Answer (score -4):

Note that the Debug Log is longer than just one line (you can see it by clicking on said line).
You can try to use `Debug.ClearDeveloperConsole()` and see what you get.