# How to make handles in a line editor rotate by rotating game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

[image]

I have been trying to make the handles (from the nodes) in [GoKit](https://github.com/prime31/GoKit) rotate by rotating the game object. Basically I added GoKit to my project and made a game object with the [GoDummyPath](https://github.com/prime31/GoKit/blob/075d20d7f5cc7e917e65a357367fa3dea44fa799/Assets/Plugins/GoKit/GoDummyPath.cs) script attached. I only used two nodes (or handles) to create a straight line.
The image above shows what I want to achieve. From an original position A, I would want to rotate the game object to affect the positions of the handles (the line) to say B. The small circle represents the position of the game object.

I couldn't rotate the line by rotating the game object in the inspector, so I added the following code to the `GoDummyPathEditor`:

Two variables:

```
private Quaternion handleRotation;
private Transform handleTransform;
```

to `OnEnable()`

```
handleTransform = _target.transform;
    handleRotation = Tools.pivotRotation == PivotRotation.Local ?
        handleTransform.rotation : Quaternion.identity;

    for (var i = 0; i < _target.nodes.Count; i++)
        _target.nodes [i] = handleTransform.TransformPoint (_target.nodes [i]);
```

`if( GUI.changed )` of `OnInspectorGUI()`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _target.nodes.Count; i++)
            _target.nodes [i] = handleTransform.InverseTransformPoint(_target.nodes [i]);
```

I replaced:

```
Handles.Label( _target.nodes[i] + new Vector3( 3f, 0, 1.5f ), i.ToString(), _indexStyle );
```

with:

```
_target.nodes[i] = Handles.DoPositionHandle(_target.nodes[i], handleRotation);
```

The full changed [GoDummyPathEditor](https://pastebin.com/gDeSJzDn)

I still cannot move the handles. I don't know what I'm missing here. How can I rotate the handles by rotating the game object through the inspector rotation property?

Comment: your link to the full file points to an empty pastebin.

Comment: @otomo sorry about that. Just fixed the replaced the link.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to achieve. Maybe try attaching a screenshot. If you want to rotate the node handles with the gameobject transform bear in mind that the nodes in this plugin only have a position vector3. They are not meant to have a rotation.

Comment: @otomo I just updated the question. The main thing I want to achieve here is rotating the handles by rotating the game object. Though the plugin doesn't have that functionality I really need it and want to implement it. That's why I made the above changes which are not working.

Comment: @otomo I added an image that I think better explains what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: See the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.PositionHandle.html) which provided a complete example of how to use the Handles in the Editor

Comment: @Programmer from my understanding of the linked doc the rotation should have been working originally, which isn't the case.